# MongoDB query for finding number of people with conflicting schedules

Tags: mongodb

For the example data below I am trying to find the number of people (userID) that have conflicting schedules. Conflicting schedules means any schedule that have overlap between start and end.

```
    {
    "_id": "1",
    "userID": "123",
    "start": "1",
    "end": "5"
}, {
    "_id": "2",
    "userID": "123",
    "start": "4",
    "end": "5"
}, {
    "_id": "3",
    "userID": "124",
    "start": "1",
    "end": "5"
}, {
    "_id": "4",
    "userID": "124",
    "start": "7",
    "end": "8"
}
```

In the example above userID 123 has conflicting schedule because start1:1, end1:5 and start2:4,end2:5 overlap. No other user has overlapping schedules. So total number of user with conflicting schedule is 1. Also to note, a user may have any number of schedules in the data.

My attempt so far has been using mongodb's aggregation to group all the start and end for one userID in one place.

```
[{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$userID",
        "schedules": {
            "$push": {
                "start": "$start",
                "end": "$end"
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

This is format of the result I get.

```
{
    "schedules": [
      {
        "start": 1,
        "end": 5
      },
      {
        "start": 4,
        "end": 5
      }
    ],
    "_id": "123"
  }
```

Now I need to check for conflict of schedules for each userID and count the number of users with conflicts.

Comment: @JohnnyHK No. This is a real task I need to figure out for my application. I am new to mongodb so I am looking for some help.

Comment: It may not be homework, but the question has already been asked by yourself. If you have questions about what was already answered then ask of the person who already answered your question instead of posting a new question. Believe me that if it warrants a new question, I'll actually tell you. But the solutions to "finding overlaps/conflicts" has already been given there.